# Is there a way to extract the list of components of a React Native project programmatically?

Tags: react-native, appium

The problem that we are trying to solve is to ensure that ALL components of a React Native project will have a testID attribute and thus can be more easily be found by Appium.

Therefore the need is to have a script which is capable to scan all javascript files which contain components, parsing the attributes of these components and check if `testID` attribute is present or missing.
The end result should be a list of components which are missing the testID attribute.

Is there such a script already available ? Or any kind of script that can iterate over all the components of a React Native project in order to execute a custom script on them ?